# kvm virtio VM sound issues (windows 10)

Tags: linux, virtualization, kvm

I'm trying to get my first unraid server to work since Thursday and got pretty everything working so far and I am satisfied. But I need the sound to work on my MainVM (Gaming VM) and an other VM. I tried to pass my motherboard sound card through but no luck I get choppy sound when I use it. I tried my corsair vengence 2100 headset which is usb and get barely no sound from it and same thing from  my G930 headset (also USB). Is it a known issue? Is there a workarround? This is the last thing I need to get working.

There is my rig setup:

```
I7 4930k @4.5ghz 
32 GB of ram @ 2400 mhz G.SKILL Ripjaws
GPU1:HD4770<- unRAID
GPU2:GTX780<- Gaming VM
HDDs:
Array:
1xWD 4GB I think it's a blue<- NAS shares (some use cache) and windows server 2012
1X 750GB HDD seagate SATAIII
Unassigned:
1XSamsung PRO SSD 512GB<- Gaming VM and an other little VM
```

My VM XML:

```
<domain type='kvm' id='30' xmlns:qemu='http://libvirt.org/schemas/domain/qemu/1.0'>
  <name>MainVM</name>
  <uuid>513cb2b9-423d-78d2-45ac-4f64ebe79b81</uuid>
  <description>Gaming and Media</description>
  <metadata>
    <vmtemplate name="Custom" icon="windows.png" os="windows"/>
  </metadata>
  <memory unit='KiB'>10485760</memory>
  <currentMemory unit='KiB'>10485760</currentMemory>
  <memoryBacking>
    <nosharepages/>
    <locked/>
  </memoryBacking>
  <vcpu placement='static'>8</vcpu>
  <cputune>
    <vcpupin vcpu='0' cpuset='0'/>
    <vcpupin vcpu='1' cpuset='1'/>
    <vcpupin vcpu='2' cpuset='2'/>
    <vcpupin vcpu='3' cpuset='3'/>
    <vcpupin vcpu='4' cpuset='4'/>
    <vcpupin vcpu='5' cpuset='5'/>
    <vcpupin vcpu='6' cpuset='6'/>
    <vcpupin vcpu='7' cpuset='7'/>
  </cputune>
  <resource>
    <partition>machine</partition>
  </resource>
  <os>
    <type arch='x86_64' machine='pc-i440fx-2.3'>hvm</type>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
  </features>
  <cpu mode='host-passthrough'>
    <topology sockets='1' cores='8' threads='1'/>
  </cpu>
  <clock offset='localtime'>
    <timer name='rtc' tickpolicy='catchup'/>
    <timer name='pit' tickpolicy='delay'/>
    <timer name='hpet' present='no'/>
  </clock>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>restart</on_crash>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64</emulator>
    <disk type='file' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw' cache='writeback'/>
      <source file='/mnt/disks/Samsung_SSD_840_PRO_Series_S1AXNSADA12984T/MainVM/vdisk1.img'/>
      <backingStore/>
      <target dev='hdc' bus='virtio'/>
      <boot order='1'/>
      <alias name='virtio-disk2'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x04' function='0x0'/>
    </disk>
    <disk type='file' device='cdrom'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
      <source file='/mnt/user/ISO/Windows10.iso'/>
      <backingStore/>
      <target dev='hda' bus='ide'/>
      <readonly/>
      <boot order='2'/>
      <alias name='ide0-0-0'/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' target='0' unit='0'/>
    </disk>
    <disk type='file' device='cdrom'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
      <source file='/mnt/user/ISO/virtio-win-0.1.113.iso'/>
      <backingStore/>
      <target dev='hdb' bus='ide'/>
      <readonly/>
      <alias name='ide0-0-1'/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' target='0' unit='1'/>
    </disk>
    <controller type='usb' index='0'>
      <alias name='usb'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x2'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='0' model='pci-root'>
      <alias name='pci.0'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='ide' index='0'>
      <alias name='ide'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x1'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='virtio-serial' index='0'>
      <alias name='virtio-serial0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
    </controller>
    <interface type='bridge'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:cf:b0:2b'/>
      <source bridge='br0'/>
      <target dev='vnet2'/>
      <model type='virtio'/>
      <alias name='net0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
    <serial type='pty'>
      <source path='/dev/pts/2'/>
      <target port='0'/>
      <alias name='serial0'/>
    </serial>
    <console type='pty' tty='/dev/pts/2'>
      <source path='/dev/pts/2'/>
      <target type='serial' port='0'/>
      <alias name='serial0'/>
    </console>
    <channel type='unix'>
      <source mode='bind' path='/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/channel/target/MainVM.org.qemu.guest_agent.0'/>
      <target type='virtio' name='org.qemu.guest_agent.0' state='disconnected'/>
      <alias name='channel0'/>
      <address type='virtio-serial' controller='0' bus='0' port='1'/>
    </channel>
    <hostdev mode='subsystem' type='usb' managed='yes'>
      <source>
        <vendor id='0x045e'/>
        <product id='0x0291'/>
        <address bus='10' device='5'/>
      </source>
      <alias name='hostdev0'/>
    </hostdev>
    <hostdev mode='subsystem' type='usb' managed='yes'>
      <source>
        <vendor id='0x04b3'/>
        <product id='0x3025'/>
        <address bus='10' device='4'/>
      </source>
      <alias name='hostdev1'/>
    </hostdev>
    <hostdev mode='subsystem' type='usb' managed='yes'>
      <source>
        <vendor id='0x17ef'/>
        <product id='0x6019'/>
        <address bus='10' device='100'/>
      </source>
      <alias name='hostdev2'/>
    </hostdev>
    <memballoon model='virtio'>
      <alias name='balloon0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x0'/>
    </memballoon>
  </devices>
  <qemu:commandline>
    <qemu:arg value='-device'/>
    <qemu:arg value='ioh3420,bus=pci.0,addr=1c.0,multifunction=on,port=2,chassis=1,id=root.1'/>
    <qemu:arg value='-device'/>
    <qemu:arg value='vfio-pci,host=03:00.0,bus=root.1,addr=00.0,multifunction=on,x-vga=on'/>
    <qemu:arg value='-device'/>
    <qemu:arg value='vfio-pci,host=03:00.1,bus=root.1,addr=00.1'/>
  </qemu:commandline>
</domain>
```

Thanks
Alex

Comment: Did you solve this? A comment would be appreciated. You can even answer your own question and mark it as answered ;)

Comment: I didn't ... Actually I do not have this setup anymore...

Comment: I managed to get some similar set-up working quite good using AC97 emulation and Alsa sound driver with Win10 guest on a Debian host. The tricky part was just to install the AC97 driver within Win10, which usually fails due of the unsigned AC97 driver. Hence this check has to be disabled for this single driver.